# How to set ip address for AppModel wildcard IIS binding

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I am working with a provider-hosted on-premise app deployment.

I have three DNS entries, which all resolve to the SharePoint server:

1. Internal.fake.net 123.156.78.90
2. External.fake.net 134.167.89.10
3. *.fakeApps.net    145.178.91.1

The internal and external are for separate SharePoint Applications, for which I can easily configure the ip address bindings in IIS.

However, for the AppModel apps, I must use the wildcard entry to ensure that the App Web(s) url(s) can resolve.

How do I tell SharePoint and/or IIS to bind to the specified IP address for the generated app web urls that the AppModel creates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint doesn't actually care very much about which application you bind the wildcard dns entry for the AppModel to.

The only requirements seem to be that:

1. The SharePoint application to which the wildcard is bound has the following Service Application Connections

   - App Management Service
   - App Management Service Application Proxy
2. The web application has all the same authentication types enabled as *any* site that will use the AppModel apps.

   - In other words, if you have one site that uses form based authentication and another site that uses Windows authentication, then your "routing" application must have both Windows and Forms authentication enabled.
   - If you are missing an authentication method, you may get underlying 403 forbidden errors (though they may show up as different errors unless you dig deeply enough) - which in my case manifested as the SharePoint chrome control not displaying correctly.

So in some cases, you can just add the wildcard binding for the app model to an existing site in IIS.

However, in my particular case, I created a separate SharePoint application (with no site collections attached) that met the above requirements.  After SharePoint finished creating the web application, I wend into IIS Manager and edited the bindings to associate it with the "*.fakeApps.net" ip address and wildcard SSL cert.